Asymptotics: How to simplify the term $s_0 = \alpha_1 n^{\beta_1} + \alpha_2 n^{\beta_2} \pm n^{\beta_1-1-\varepsilon}$
Assume  $s_0 = \alpha_1 n^{\beta_1} + \alpha_2 n^{\beta_2} \pm n^{\beta_1-1-\varepsilon}$, with $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$ and $\beta_1 > \beta_2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Can we deduce that $s_0 = (1+\mathcal{o}(1))(\alpha_1 n^{\beta_1} + \alpha_2 n^{\beta_2})$?

Give more details about your problem

I made an edit.

Hint: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{n^{\beta _1  - 1 - \varepsilon } }}{{\alpha _1 n^{\beta _1 }  + \alpha _2 n^{\beta 2 } }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{n^{ - 1 - \varepsilon } }}{{\alpha _1  + \alpha _2 n^{\beta _2  - \beta _1 } }} = \frac{0}{{\alpha _1  + \alpha _2  \cdot 0}} = 0
$$

@3nondatur Could you proceed?

@Gary: Yes, thank you.
